Docker desktop installation in windows 10 fails with 'Access to path is denied'
I am trying to install docker desktop via command prompt to my D: drive in a specific folder.
D:/dkr

I am using the command line to do so using the following command.
 start /w "" "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install -accept-license  --installation-dir=D:\dkr

However, during the installation, I get an error and installation stops. This is the entire traceback/message of the error:
Version: 4.29.0 (145265)
Sha1:
Started on: 2024/05/03 04:56:25.589
Resources: D:\Users\asavaria\Downloads\resources
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Edition: Professional
Id: 2009
Build: 19045
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\install-log-admin.txt
CommandLine: "Docker Desktop Installer.exe"  install -accept-license  --installation-dir=D:\dkr
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[2024-05-03T04:56:26.015646100Z][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader][I] Install path is D:\dkr. Loading manifest first
[2024-05-03T04:56:26.024613100Z][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader][I] No manifest found, returning no existing install
[2024-05-03T04:56:26.025192000Z][Installer][I] No installation found
[2024-05-03T04:56:26.278901500Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[2024-05-03T04:56:26.279907900Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Downloading
[2024-05-03T04:56:27.862863300Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Extracting manifest
[2024-05-03T04:56:28.793194500Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Manifest found: version=145265, displayVersion=4.29.0, channelUrl=https://desktop-stage.docker.com/win/main/amd64/appcast.xml
[2024-05-03T04:56:28.793194500Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Checking prerequisites
[2024-05-03T04:56:29.152217100Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Prompting for optional features
[2024-05-03T04:56:36.659889300Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Selected backend mode: wsl-2
[2024-05-03T04:56:36.662840900Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Unpacking artifacts
[2024-05-03T04:56:36.715412500Z][InstallWorkflow][E] Installation failed System.Exception: Unpacking failed: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultSd)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()
   at Docker.Core.PermissionUtils.RemoveGlobalWrite(ILogger logger, String path) in C:\workspaces\PR-27407\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PermissionUtils.cs:line 47
   at Docker.Installer.UnpackArtifactsStep.<DoAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Installer.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
[2024-05-03T04:56:36.723243100Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Rollbacking component Docker.Installer.ExtractManifestStep
[2024-05-03T04:56:36.724245000Z][InstallWorkflow][I] Rollbacking component Docker.Installer.DownloadStep
[2024-05-03T04:56:36.725815700Z][InstallWorkflow-DownloadStep][I] Failed to delete package: Access to the path 'D:\dkr\dockerinstallerpackage' is denied.

Earlier, when I created the folder, I could access it but after this error, I am unable to even open the folder.
I am doing this on my work computer and I am not on the admin user, however, the installation was done with admin privileges with the help of IT.
How do I go about installing docker desktop in this situation. Please note that I have to install it in D: and not it C:.
Thank You for the answers
